Excel VBA - Comparing 2 Comma-Separated Number Strings - Appending Non-Overlapping Numbers From 2nd String
I've been reviewing multiple questions and have not come across my exact issue. Fairly new to VBA, but generally have been able to muddle through if I know where to start. So, I'm not looking for anyone to hand me a solution (although any assistance is appreciated). Here's what I'm trying to do. I have two comma-separated strings (String 1 and String 2) of generally 5 to 10 numbers. String 2 is generally a continuation of "some" portion of String 1. As an example let's assume String 1 is 4,15,30,22,60,54,21 and String 2 is 22,60,54,21,2,10,6. So, in my example 22,60,54,21 overlaps a portion of String 1. What I would like to end up with is a combined string of 4,15,30,22,60,54,21,2,10,6 such that the overlapping portion of the number string is not duplicated. The overlap could be variable, meaning on occasion it could be 1-2 numbers and another could be 4-6 numbers.
I have tried to accomplish this by using a bunch of helper columns or rows with some success, but I would want to employ a solution over more than two cell sets. In my research it "seems" as though the correct area would be StrComp and/or InStr. Again, thanks to anyone willing to give a bit of direction.

Can the numbers repeated in any of the groups?

I'm thinking use Split to get the strings into arrays. Step through each array and add to a Dictionary if not already in there. Then convert the Dictionary back into an array vArray = oDict.Keys. Finally use Join to bring it all back together res = Join(vArray, ",")

This is really an algorithmic question rather than anything VBA-specific. Black cat's question is critical. If numbers might be non-unique, more definition is needed: for example, what return value would you expect if string 1 is 1,2,3,2,3 and string 2 is 2,3,2,3,4?

First, thanks for the quick responses. As I'm more of a novice, I will need to interpret what everyone has given. To answer Black cat's question, it is possible that numbers may be repeated, but I was hoping that is there was sufficient overlap that whatever solution that I can employ would yield the correct match, if that makes sense. And, to specifically address Neil T's question, it is possible, but extremely rare that the numbers would repeat with such frequency.

Again, I appreciate everyone's responses. I'll have to work my way through them. CLR, the description of yours seems to closely mimic what I was doing with a bunch of helpers and IF statements. I'll give them all a go and see where I end up and report back. Thanks.

CLR - Your answer achieved the result that I was looking for. I need to tweak it somewhat for my purposes, but the framework given is very helpful. Thanks to the others who responded. While each of the answers may also achieve my desired result, with my more limited experience it requires more research and testing to implement. But I do appreciate your willingness to help.

Here is a different way of achieving your goal, that I think more closely resembles how a human might do it:
Sub Remove_overlapping_duplicates()

 Dim str1 As String, str2 As String, str3 As String, strlen as long, n As Long
 str1 = "4,15,30,22,60,54,21"
 str2 = "22,60,54,21,2,10,6"
 str3 = str1 & "," & str2
 
 'get shortest string
 strlen = Len(str1)
 If Len(str2) < strlen Then strlen = Len(str2)
 
 'loop through
 For n = strlen To 1 Step -1
    If Left(str2, n) = Right(str1, n) Then
       str3 = str1 & Mid(str2, n + 1)
       Exit For
    End If
 Next
 
 'output answer
 MsgBox str3
 
End Sub

It starts with the shortest of the two string lengths, and starts attempting to match the entirety of str2 against str1. It then repeats, shortening the length each time until a match is found. The first match found with the most characters wins through and the output is produced. If no match is found at all, str1 & str2 are output.
You can see it working here:
4,15,30,22,60,54, | ,15,30,22,60,54,21 | 
                  | 22,60,54,21,2,10,6 | 

4,15,30,22,60,54 | 15,30,22,60,54,21 | 
                 | 22,60,54,21,2,10, | 6

4,15,30,22,60,5 | 5,30,22,60,54,21 | 
                | 22,60,54,21,2,10 | ,6

4,15,30,22,60, | ,30,22,60,54,21 | 
               | 22,60,54,21,2,1 | 0,6

4,15,30,22,60 | 30,22,60,54,21 | 
              | 22,60,54,21,2, | 10,6

4,15,30,22,6 | 0,22,60,54,21 | 
             | 22,60,54,21,2 | ,10,6

4,15,30,22, | ,22,60,54,21 | 
            | 22,60,54,21, | 2,10,6

4,15,30,22 | 22,60,54,21 | 
           | 22,60,54,21 | ,2,10,6    << match found


Please, try the next code.  It only puts in practice @CHill60 suggestion. So, all credit should go to him. It assumes that overlapping also means the same not unique strings in only one string. It practically removes duplicates from both strings:
Sub RemoveOverlapping_Duplicates()
 Dim str1 As String, str2 As String, str3 As String, arr, i As Long, dict As Object
 str1 = "4,15,30,22,60,54,21"
 str2 = "22,60,54,21,2,10,6"
 
 arr = Split(str1 & "," & str2, ",") 'place both concatenated strings (comma separated) and split by comma
 
 Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")     'able to keep only unique keys
 For i = 0 To UBound(arr): dict(arr(i)) = "": Next i 'load the dictionary
 str3 = Join(dict.keys, ",") 'returned string
 MsgBox str3
End Sub


The dictionary solution came to my mind also as first idea. It has the small drawbacks that a) it needs the Dictionary-object that is not available on Macs and b) if one of the lists contains a number twice on purpose, you would loose it (no idea if this is an issue in your case).
Just for fun, I did a solution that checks if the right part of the first string ("tail") is equal to the left part of the second string.
Function JoinOverlapping(s1 As String, s2 As String)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s1)
        Dim tail As String
        tail = Mid(s1, i)
        If Mid(s1, i) = Left(s2, Len(tail)) Then
            JoinOverlapping = s1 & Mid(s2, Len(tail) + 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    JoinOverlapping = s1 & "," & s2
End Function

For your example, at position i=9 of the first string, the function will find the tail = 22,60,54,21 (with a length of 11) and therefore will skip the first 11 characters of the second string.
You can use the function either in your code
Sub Test1
    Debug.Print JoinOverlapping("4,15,30,22,60,54,21","22,60,54,21,2,10,6")
End Sub

or for example as UDF (=User defined Function) as formula in Excel:
=JoinOverlapping(a1, b2)

